# Removing object by matching string in it

Tags: javascript

I have an array where are objects. Here's one example::

```
color:"rgb(235, 75, 75)"
id:"6912128558"
img:""
name:"AWP | Dragon Lore (Factory New)"
price:"1852.2"
```

If I would forEach loop that array and if price `>=` with total, then it's going to remove the full object. I hope it makes sense.

Comment: So, so, so, what exactly are you trying to do without a `total`?

Comment: Total is example, `var total = 1000;`

Comment: Why is testing that price is greater than total "matching string"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a new array by filtering the objects you want to keep

```
var cheapObjects = allObjects.filter(o => o.price < total); // whatever "total" is
```

or the legacy equivalent

```
allObjects.filter(function(o) { return o.price < 1000 })
```

See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter